# Batch File to Create Multiple Symbolic Links

Tags: batch-file, symlink

I've looked around a little bit and have tried different things but haven't had any luck. I'm not very good with batch when it comes to "for loops" but I think this is exactly what I need to accomplish my goal.

Ok, so I have 35 symbolic links to create. The thing is, there will be more of these that I will have to create starting very soon, and they will usually be in the dozens, so a script is the way to go here for sure.

**My goal:**
I have a folder: `F:\Browser Downloads\Ortho4XP\Tiles\Cuba\` 
This folder includes 35 sub-folders (I need all the contents of those folders in the symbolic link)
**Example sub-folders:**

```
zOrtho4XP_+20-074
zOrtho4XP_+25-077
zOrtho4XP_+22-073
zOrtho4XP_+23-075
zOrtho4XP_+23-079

... and so on
```

I need a symbolic link to be created for each of those sub-folders above in the following directory:

```
E:\X Plane 11\X-Plane 11\Custom Scenery\Ortho\Cuba
```

How would I script something like this?

I deeply appreciate any help with this. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Use the FOR command with the /D option to iterate all the folders. Use the MKLINK command to create the symbolic link.

Comment: See `for /?`, especially `/d`, and `mklink /?`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies. I forgot to mention in the OP that I have tried some lines similar to this one but with no avail: `for /d %%g in ("F:\Browser Downloads\Ortho4XP\Tiles\Cuba") do mklink /d %%g *` I'm especially having trouble, as you can probably tell, by the part where I need it to name the symbolic link the same name as the sub-folder, and then after that for it to have the full path to that sub-folder.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Batch rather than Powershell, you can write far more robust code this way, or is this for Windows XP or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "target=F:\Browser Downloads\Ortho4XP\Tiles\Cuba"
set "destination=E:\X Plane 11\X-Plane 11\Custom Scenery\Ortho\Cuba"

for /d %%A in ("%target%\*") do mklink /d "%destination%\%%~nxA" "%%~A"
```

The modifier of `nx` in `%%~nxA` gets the folder name.
See `for /?` about modifiers.

`mklink` requires Admin privileges.

Comment: What about files? Working for folders only

Comment: @JaberAlNahian The Q&A is about the sub-folders. For files, would require a different `for` loop and `mklink` would require `/d` to be removed. You can view `for /?` and `mklink /?` for help with the command. E.g. `for %%A in ("%target%\*.txt") do mklink "%destination%\%%~nxA" "%%~A"`.